# How to dynamically retrieve string inputs in textField in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, dynamic, textfield

I'm trying to create a payment method activity in Android.

I've seen lots of website recognizing my text input (credit card number) DYNAMICALLY so if I put first 3~4 digits, it knows if the card is VISA, MASTER, etc .. before I even finish typing.

What I thought to do was to update the String value I get from getText() method each time an user types. but don't know where to start so far!

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin *EditText

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. The category's name from XML editor said "text fields" so I used that, but it IS editText. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a listener to the EditText and then override the methods you are interested to take custom actions. Here is an example how you can do it. http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can attach to the EditText a listener being notified when the text change, this is natively supported by the android framework:
As an example:

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //perform checks or implement logic on what the user has entered so far here...
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Comment: So I tried to do that, but it won't update the value of s. 
For example, I made a few if statements to see :
if( s.equals("4")) {
Log.d(TAG,"VISA"); }
else if ( s.equals("5")) {
Log.d(TAG,"MASTER CARD");}

etc..

then if I put 4 something, if I completely remove and retype something that starts with 5, it would still print VISA in the Logcat. Why is it doing that?

Thank you for replying.

Comment: It was the Type problem. I couldn't use toString method on Editable somehow, but I could on CharSequence. So I decided to use onTextChanged() method instead of afterTextChanged(). Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Editable has the method gettext() if I am not mistaken, you are welcome :)